# Subversion not available in Xamarin Studio anymore

Tags: svn, xamarin-studio

today morning I've updated Xamarin Studio to latest 6.2 (build 1821). Now I've seen that subversion is not available in Version Control anymore. I've checked the Add-ins and Subversion support (Version 6.2) is listed and enabled as expected. I've also tried disabling, restarting etc. of course, but no changes.

Nevertheless my project is not under version control anymore even though it worked fine with SVN for weeks. Now in "Version Control" menu I only have "Checkout" enabled, and there I could only select Type Git, no subversion anymore.

As proposed here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-studio/version-control/ I've also called "svn h" from terminal and it worked fine. I've also called "svn info" within my repository and it shows the correct data so subversion itself is working fine.

Any ideas how to get Subversion in Xamarin Studio running again?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the below link, seems like the svn functionality is broken in the latest version of Xamarin.

[Issue Raised in Xamarin Forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/89566/svn-not-working-on-latest-version-of-xs-6-2)

The only bet is to downgrade for the time being till the issue is resolved.

Comment: Or switching to git (which I did in the meantime).